# Modification JSON with input html in js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm learning JS and i'm trying to make a little app with node.js with JSON on.

I managed to get what I wanted in my json and put it in my html as input, with the json data as "value". When I click on the elements, we can change each of them, since they are inputs, and so I change their "value". Until then, everything works, but when I modify my 1st element of the list, all the elements are modified in the json...
And only the first element in my HTML changes my json, the others don't, they change but don't register in the json, and I have trouble understanding why.. I tried forEach and this.el but nothing works, it doesn't understand my data..

There is the code

```
var newValue = $("#snippetTitle").on("change paste keyup", function () {
    if (newValue.val() != $("#snippetTitle:input")) {
        for (var i = 0; i < jsonParse.snippets.length; i++) {
            newValueTitle = jsonParse.snippets[i].title = newValue.val();
            writeValue = JSON.stringify(jsonParse, newValueTitle);
            fs.writeFileSync('save/snippets.json', writeValue, 'utf8');
        }
    } else {
    }
});
```

Thank you for explaining to me how I could do so that each element could be modifiable, and especially that it is recorded in the json...
I'm not looking for complete solutions, just help to understand what to do.

Comment: `if (newValue.val() /* string */ != $("#snippetTitle:input") /* object */)` will never be `false`